# Objective-C: NSString.alloc.init, how's it look?

Tags: objective-c

The syntax is legal. It'll save you about 2 seconds every time you alloc/init an object. Do you think this could be a new trend?

Again,

`NSObject *obj = NSObject.alloc.init;`

Comment: as far as I know, dot notation is a sugar coat in ObjCpp and compiler will transform `NSObject.alloc.init` into `[[NSObject alloc]init]` 
Not a new trend - just a convenience.

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSObject new];
```

Saves even more and doesn't cause any religious wars.

Comment: Ahem... I represent the church of custom initializers.  We'd like a word with you about your offensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it saves a few keystrokes, but I doubt it will catch on. See this blog post for a number of cases where [using dot notation on methods rather than properties will not work](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/06/crazy-objectivec-dot-notation/). I think most people view this as a side effect of ObjC2.

Furthermore, I don't think it enhances readability at all. As soon as you want to send a message with an argument, you have to revert back to the original syntax.

Comment: Don't think dot notation is there to send message rather that accession setter/getter - in that case it is really convenient and readable. At least for ppl from C++ :)